# Portion of outlets not working

Tags: electrical

Seeking some help.  Breaker is fine.  Other outlets on same circuit working.  Everything downstream of light switch is not working.  Light switch appears fine.  Back stabber outlets not working, neutral to ground is live, hot to ground is live, neutral to hot is not.

Also note, was  using space heater.  Popped the breaker the first time.  Then after flipped the tripped circuit back on, the outlet the heater was plugged into plus the 6 outlets upstream of it to the light switch that powers them stopped working.  Help.

Comment: Neutral to ground should be 0 volts. Hot to ground, and hot to neutral should be line voltage (120 volts). Sounds like you might want to call in an Electrician. Also, you should probably unplug that heater.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I have an electrician coming in tuesday.  Agreed...heater is gone already.

Comment: Why would neutral to ground be delivering line voltage of 120 volts?  My voltage tester reads the same for each of the outlets in question.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sounds like the neutral line is energized, possibly shorted to hot.

Comment: What test did you do to decide " Light switch appears fine. "